# How to pass context variable from template to views.py in python django?

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have this my views.py

```
def exampleclass1(request):
     #do other things

     examplevar = request.POST.getlist('id[]')
     data_dicts = [{'id': id} for id in examplevar]
     for data in data_dicts:
         master_data=ExampleModel.objects.get(id=data.get('id'))
         master_data.save()
     context={
         'sampleid':examplevar,
     }

    #do other things

    return render(request, 'examplepage.html',context)
```

In my examplepage.html, I have this line:

```
<a href="{% url 'exampleclass2' sampleid %}"></a>
```

My exampleclass2 looks like this in my views.py :

```
def exampleclass2(request,sampleid):
    examplevar = sampleid
    data_dicts = [{'id': id} for id in examplevar]
    for data in data_dicts:
        master_data=ExampleModel.objects.get(id=data.get('id'))
        master_data.save()
```

What I am trying to do is pass 'sampleid' context variable from 'exampleclass1' to 'examplepage' template and then pass that 'sampleid' from 'examplepage' template to 'exampleclass2'. What will be my urlpattern in my urls.py ? How can I achieve this ?

Comment: `sampleid` is a list of ids in your code example. To my understanding it is not possibe to setup a url pattern that can pick up a list directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, I just need to be sure that there is no possible way to setup a url pattern that can pick up a list directly. If there is then I need to know what is the way to achieve that. I guess sampleid looks like this: ('[1]','[2]','[3]').

Comment: Either modify the structure of `sampleid` or use this urlpattern `r'^example2/(?P<sampleid>.*)'` and then sampleid in example2 view will be a string containing a list which you can parse into a list with the help of `json` module.